# Why is my query returning an unexpected result?

Tags: oracle

Here are the tables I am using:

- parts(pid,pname,color)
- suppliers(sid,sname,address)
- catalog(sid,pid,cost)

I need to find the name of suppliers that supply two different parts with the same price. I keep getting the incorrect answer.

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Supplers S
WHERE S.sid IN (SELECT C.pid
FROM Catalog C, Catalog C1, Parts P, Parts P1
WHERE C1.sid = C.sid  AND P.pid = P1.pid AND C1.cost = C.cost);
```

Comment: Any chance of an [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with that?

Answer (score 2):

My best guess is that what you are actually trying to query is:

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Suppliers S
WHERE S.sid IN (SELECT C.sid
FROM Catalog C, Catalog C1
WHERE C1.pid <> C.pid  AND C1.cost = C.cost);
```

I changed the subselect to return `C.sid`, and removed the `parts` table altogether, since in your original body text you stated no conditions on the table.

Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes, Thanks I'm a beginner with a professor that is not much help

Answer (score 1):

For Chris's answer, doesn't that give the answer across different suppliers? Shouldn't it be for the same supplier? So would the SQL be (using Chris's SQL):

```
SELECT S.sname
FROM Suppliers S
WHERE S.sid IN (SELECT C.sid
FROM Catalog C, Catalog C1
WHERE C1.pid <> C.pid  AND C1.cost = C.cost and c1.sid = c2.sid);
```

Comment: Are you saying or asking this?

Comment: The original question doesn't specify if it's for the same supplier or different suppliers. Either way it would be an assumption.